# Tag synonym/merge request [zelda] → [the-legend-of-zelda]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-rename-request

I'd like to request that [zelda](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda) be made a synonym/merged with [the-legend-of-zelda](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-legend-of-zelda).

Answer (score 7):

[zelda](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda) to [legend-of-zelda](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-of-zelda) makes sense, but [zelda-classic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-classic) refers to a [specific version of the game.](http://www.zeldaclassic.com/)

Comment: I thought one of the first two was supposed to be for the series, and the other for the first game.  badp knows.  I proposed `zelda-series` but maybe that was forgotten.

Comment: @MatthewRead There's just no question about the Zelda series afaik

Comment: @badp How about the first one shown when I click `zelda`?  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26031/which-hand-does-link-have-the-triforce-on

Comment: @MatthewRead There is a [tag:zelda-series] tag.

Comment: @lesspop-morefizz The wiki for [tag:zelda-classic] should indicate that is is not referring to the original _Legend of Zelda_, but a [fan game](http://www.zeldaclassic.com/what.php). I'll withdraw [tag:zelda-classic] once the wiki is updated.

Comment: @CyberSkull Ah, perfect.  I've cleaned up `zelda` so that it solely refers to `legend-of-zelda` and not `zelda-series`.  This merge proposed by LessPop_MoreFizz should work now.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [comments](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2928/tag-synonym-request-merge-zelda-%E2%86%92-legend-of-zelda/15516#comment7606_2929) on LessPop's post - [zelda](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda) was cleaned up, with all questions being retagged to [the-legend-of-zelda](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-legend-of-zelda), but a synonym was not created.

A synonym would be rather benign here, as the main tag already includes the word 'zelda'. If someone were to search 'zelda' in the tag box, the appropriate tags would appear anyway.

Plus, there's plenty of other zelda games!